# Add variables to all permalinks in site

Tags: permalinks

I need to add variables to all links in my site based on a condition.

So all permalink in a page that met my condition (in specific category or whatever) :

> www.domain.com/exemple-page or
>
> www.domain.com/category/cars

would be

> www.domain.com/exemple-page?var=1 and
>
> www.domain.com/category/cars?var=1

How can I do that?

Comment: You mean for links on the whole page, including sidebar, content, comments, navbar, ... ? In that case I think a Javascript solution would be suitable.

Comment: Only on the internal links (so we're excluding comments). I think i should do something on the permalink but don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All permalink output has filters you can use to modify it: `post_link`, `post_type_link`, `page_link`, `tag_link`, `category_link`, `term_link`.

A simple example with `page_link`:

```
function wpd_append_query_string( $url, $id ) {
    // check some condition and add a query string var
    if( some_condition ) {
        $url = add_query_arg( 'var', 1, $url );
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'page_link', 'wpd_append_query_string', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Great. Any ideas how to change url's in the_content()?